# R Shiny - 'container' argument in `renderDT` not allowing customisation of table styling classes via 'class' argument

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to turn off striping for the table below. I can do this by leaving the `stripe` class out of the `class` argument like so: `class = 'hover row-border order-column'`. This works on its own but when I introduce a custom header via the `container` argument of `datatable()`, it no longer works.

Without container (no striping, as expected):

[image]

With container:

[image]

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js")),
    DTOutput('table')
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {  

    output$table <- renderDT({

      sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
        class = 'display',
        thead(
          tr(
            th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
            th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
            th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
          ),
          tr(
            lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
          )
        )
      ))

      datatable(
        iris,
        class = 'hover row-border order-column',
        container = sketch
      )
    }, server = F)

  }
)
```

Comment: Try to set the class(es) in `withTags(table(class = ......`

Answer (score 0):

Class `display` in `sketch` seems to be the problem:
As it is Short-hand for the stripe, hover, row-border and order-column classes - please see [this](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes).

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js")),
    DTOutput('table')
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {  

    output$table <- renderDT({

      sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
        thead(
          tr(
            th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
            th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
            th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
          ),
          tr(
            lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
          )
        )))

      datatable(
        iris,
        # callback = JS(get_selected_rows),
        class = 'hover row-border order-column',
        container = sketch
      )
    }, server = FALSE)
  }
)
```

---

[image: Result]

Comment: I think you don't need to set `class` in `datatable` if you set it in `sketch`.

Comment: I thought so too, but please try the difference. It's vice versa, we can remove it in `sketch`.